# How to expand view smoothly in Android?

Tags: android, view, layoutparams

I met an issue when I expanded a 320*50 view to full-screen.

If I expand it directly, it works but the action is very abrupt and I think is not a good user experience. So I hide the view first, then expand it, and after two second, show the view again.

```
TextView.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = TextView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

//after two seconds
handler.postDelay(new Show(),2000);

class Show implements Runnable{
   @Override
public void run(){
       TextView.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

So l left two seconds for the application to expand the view. Then after two seconds the view will show again. I am expected that the view is expanded to full-screen when it shows. But actually, it doesn't. The view do the expand action after it shows instead of during the two seconds it is hiding.

Comment: Yes, this is a excellent workaround.But Is there any resolution more directly?

Comment: @wayne_bai : I don't think there is a better way than using an Animation. They are not complex to implement.

Comment: post the 2 second-waiting part, i suspect you don't release the hand on the main thread

Comment: @njzk2:I just use handler.postDelay(runnable,time). I have updated the code.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your `ViewGroup`.
2. Use `setVisibility()` to control the visibility of your **target** `View`.
3. If there is other `View` below you **target** `View`, add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your **outer** `ViewGroup` and following code before `setVisibility()`:

   ```
   LayoutTransition layoutTransition = rootLinearLayout.getLayoutTransition();
   layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's really late for answering this, but I'll just tell the way I chose to animate layout changes for someone in need.

Android has a special Animation class named `ScaleAnimation` where we can smoothly expand or collapse views.

Show view by expanding diagonally:

```
ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.0f,
   0, 1.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expand.setDuration(250);

view.startAnimation(expand)
```

where the constructor used is:

```
ScaleAnimation(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue)
```

So you can change values accordingly.

For example, the below example would animate view horizontally:

```
ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.1f,
   1f, 1f,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expand.setDuration(250);
```

You can change `fromX`,`toX`, `fromY` & `toY` according to the need.

For example if view is shown and you have to just expand it, put `fromX` and `fromY` to `1.0f`, and `toX`, `toY` according to the need.

Now, using the same class you can create a more cool effect for showing view by expanding view a little bit extra and then shrinking it to original size. For this purpose, `AnimationSet` will be used. So it would create a kind of bubble effect.

Below example is for creating bubble effect for showing the view:

```
AnimationSet expandAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.1f,
   0, 1.1f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expand.setDuration(250);

ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(
   1.1f, 1f,
   1.1f, 1f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
shrink.setStartOffset(250);
shrink.setDuration(120);

expandAndShrink.addAnimation(expand);
expandAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink);
expandAndShrink.setFillAfter(true);
expandAndShrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

view.startAnimation(expandAndShrink);
```